# Invoke Lambda Client returning unknown error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, uncaught-exception

I have been attempting to run a lambda function from my functions.php file on my wordpress website and I was able to do so. However, despite the lambda function being invoked, the website crashes and returns this error:

```
Warning: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE - assumed 'CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/Aws/Lambda/LambdaClient.php on line 133

Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values in /var/www/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 59

Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values in /var/www/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 59

Warning: curl_setopt_array(): Array keys must be CURLOPT constants or equivalent integer values in /var/www/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 59

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Lambda\Exception\LambdaException' with message 'Error executing "Invoke" on "https://lambda.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/helloWorld/invocations"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed. The most likely reason for the failure is that cURL was unable to rewind the body of the request and subsequent retries resulted in the same error. Turn on the debug option to see what went wrong. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47204 for more information. (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 0: The cURL request was retried 3 times and did not succeed. The most likely reason for the failure is that cURL was unable to rewind the body of the request and subsequent retries resulted in the same error. Turn on the debug option to see what went wrong. See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47204 for more information. (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) i in /var/www/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 195
```

The reason why I know it's being invoked is because I can see the invocations in AWS Lambda.

The piece of code that is generating this problem is this one:

```
$result = $client->invoke([
     'FunctionName' => 'helloWorld',
   ]);
```

For context, this is the code that creates the client based on a profile I have in the credentials text file:

```
   $client = LambdaClient::factory(array(
       'region'  => 'us-east-2',
       'version' => 'latest',
       'profile' => 'default'
     ));
```

I also tried wrapping this code in question with a try/catch. This catches the error (caught2 specifically) but does not get rid of the warnings... This is the code:

```
try {
   $result = $client->invoke([
   'FunctionName' => 'helloWorld',
]);
}
catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
   echo "caught";
}
catch(Aws\Lambda\Exception\LambdaException $e) {
   echo "caught2";
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Did you inspect CloudWatch logs for the lambda? Maybe it crashes?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, I have checked the logs and they show the result of the lambda function. But the function itself gets called more than once... I'm not sure if that's related to the problem.